# mongo php call to non-object

Tags: php, mongodb, osx-leopard

I'm using PHP Mongo with Snow Leopard and I keep getting the following errors:

> 'undefined variable' and 'trying to get property of non-object'

### What I'm trying to do:

Extract variables from a URL (similar to below) to populate a collection within a mongo db. In addition, I'm trying to capture the IP address for the user and date/time the action took place.

Here is an example of a possible URL:

```
img src="http://localhost:8888/index.php?PIN=123&CID=123&EID=456" width="1" height="1"
```

PHP/Mongo Driver script:

```
<?php
  // Connect to MongoDB @ localhost w/ login/pass
  $m = new Mongo("mongodb://login:pass@localhost");

  // Connect to DB
  $db = $m ->admin;

  // Connect to Collection
  $collection = $db ->email_opens;

  // Extract date
  $createdOn = $id->getTimestamp();
  $date_open = date('r', $createdOn);

  // Get variables from URL
  $PIN = $_GET['PIN'];
  $CID = $_GET['CID'];
  $EID = $_GET['EID'];

  // Retrieves user's IP address
  $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

  // Set array
  $obj = array('PIN' => $PIN, 'CID' => $CID, 'EID' => $EID, 'date_open' => $date_open, 'ip' => $ip); 

  // Set index
  $collection -> ensureIndex(array("id" => 1));

  // Insert collection
  $collection -> insert($obj);

  // Probably not necessary
  $connection -> close();
?>
```

Comment: Are there spaces in your original code, eg: `" $collection = $db ->email_opens;"` (the space between `$db` and `->email_opens`).  Would be helpful to mention the line number of the error, as it may just be a syntax problem.

Comment: As the previous commenter said, there are some odd spaces between the `->` in your code, but it might be a copy/paste issue. Also, where are you defining `$id` before you do `$createdOn = $id->getTimestamp();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly not an MongoDB trouble but only a php one.
As [Justin Jenkins commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464441/mongo-php-call-to-non-object#comment15135715_11464441), you are not setting $id before quering on it.

On a more MongoDB part, you are creating a useless (regarding example object you insert) on the **id** field.
You don't need to create an index on generated id, this is automatically done by mongo server. And, the exact name of the field is **_id** (with an underscore).

Comment: Justin is correct except I was trying to set an index apart from the default _id, which after testing, turned out not to be necessary.  The other minor error I ran into was authentication issues with the 'admin' user.  When setting db.addUser from the command line, I neglected to designate 'use admin' in previous attempts, which caused some frustration.  Thank you all very much for the help!